# Unable to register gdb with the server due to sql server client incompatibility

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, esri-geodatabase

There are two virtual machines:

1. One where I've created an enterprise geodatabase on a Microsft SQL 2014 server- with a Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit Operating system
2. And a second machine where ArcGIS Server 10.3 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 are installed + Microsoft SQl Server 2012 Native Client 64-bit SP1. 
   This machine has a Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit Operating system, as well.

I'm trying to publish a map service on the server with data from the enterprise gdb. When trying to register my geodatabase with the server, I get the following error:

> " The connection property set was missing a required property or the
>   property values was unrecognized. Connection was attempted with an
>   older version of SQL Server client communications software that is not
>   compatible with the SQL Server database server"

[image]

So I've search for Microsoft SQl Server 2014 Native Client but couldn't find it. There is no SQL Server 2014 Native Client.

It's the same problem as this one:  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/84553, but for me installing the 64 bit client didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This is really a conversation you should be having with Esri Tech Support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this same problem after upgrading everything to 10.3.

I just dug this up from an old e-mail from ESRI Support. Here is the main part of the information in the e-mail.

Regarding SQL Server 2014 Client:

Please refer to following web-link for downloading the installer:

1. Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: Hello, first o all thanks for your response. I've installed the driver. Now when trying to registering the gdb the error message changed to: "Underlying DBMS error [[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. No extended error.]]

Comment: You should probably post a new question but that sounds to me like a firewall issue. Are you actually part of the same domain? You might have a look at this (though it is regarding an older version). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546746/sql-server-2008-windows-auth-login-error-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain

Comment: I've created a new rule in the firewall and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the rule you defined for this to work. Thanks

Comment: Many thnx, i upgraded the windows and installed Arcgis10.5+SQLexpress14 and this post fixed my issue of connecting SQL with Arcgis.